# Why won't My App Load in https on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, https

My app https://apps.facebook.com/acroblast won't load past the loader bar on facebook.  It plays just fine in https on a browser though.

https://carboncopygames.com/acroblast_flash/acroblast.html

So I guess my question is, since I have installed SSL certificate on my server, Do I need to do anything else to make it work.  Say put stuff in my code?  And yes I updated my secure URLs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions containing no information other than links to your site and pretty much nothing but "what am I doing wrong?" will probably be closed as "not a real question". Please edit your question to provide a better description of your problem and provide more specifics. Expecting people to go to your site and wade through your code to try and figure out what you might be asking seems a little much, especially when you're asking those people to help you for free. :)

Comment: Not really. :) You basically went from "What am I doing wrong?" to "I have a certificate. Do I need to do anything else to make it work? Do I need to put 'stuff' in my code?"

Answer (score 0):

You are using SSL but loading your SWF over HTTP. This is probably what causes the app to never complete loading.

```
 SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content:
 http://carboncopygames.com/acroblast_flash/acroblast.swf cannot access
 https://carboncopygames.com/acroblast_flash/resources.swf. This may be worked around by
 calling Security.allowDomain.
    at flash.display::Loader/get content()
    at com.CopycatGames::CLoading/onComplete()
```